# WHM API with python requests

Tags: api, whm

I need help about convert this CURL to python code with requests
WHM cpanel API like this :

```
curl -H'Authorization: whm username:MYAPITOKEN' 'https://127.0.0.1:2087/json-api/applist?api.version=1'
```

i try to do this but not working

```
response = requests.get('https://127.0.0.1:2087/json-api/applist?api.version=1', headers={'Authorization': 'whm USER:MYAPITOKEN'})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'whm username:MYAPITOKEN',
}

params = (
    ('api.version', '1'),
)

response = requests.get('https://127.0.0.1:2087/json-api/applist', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Comment: Hi @Master.net if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.